# Regex Finding all two three or four capitalized words in a section

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I wish to identify and then create a list in python all stocks (Capitalized Letters) mentioned here..

The problem I have a large text doc with many areas containing 2 3 or 4 Capitalised letters however i only want to get the ones that precede a paragraph ending (stocks-to-watcch are in the following paragraph):

i.e SE, SAM, PYPL, LAD, GLOB .....etc

Not sure if non capturing groups is the way to go or whether I can do look behinds.. if I do non capturing groups to I was thinking something like this would work but it doesn't... any help greatly appreciated

```
(?<=\(stocks\-to\-watch\sare\sin\sthe\sfollowing\paragraph)\:\s+)(\b[A-Z]{2,4}\b)(?:Remember\sstrong\svolume)
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at sapien fermentum, (stocks-to-watcch are in the following paragraph):

SE  e3/3, SAM  e4/22, PYPL flag bo e5/6,  LAD bo e4/22, GLOB RS72 e5/14, CCS bo e4/28, CRL RS 81 ATH e5/7, ENTG rbo
PWR
e4/21, CAMT 3wkbo e5/11, DAR TRbo e5/6, +TFII bo e4/21, GNRC ebo e4/30,   bo e5/7, GPI bo e5/05, IESC bo e5/5, SNBR
ABG  ,      BOOT
e4/22, SHYF e5/7, TBK  bo>44.70 e4/21,   Wflag bo e4/27 ENSG bo e5/11,   >48.11 e5/20, ARCB >50 e5/5, +CSWI
TTEC
RS82 e5/20, ZBRA ebo RS83 e4/28, WD ebo bo>78.13 e5/6,  RILY Mr156 e5/11, ETSY e4/30, UCTT >Mr34.59 e4/29,
BKE       ATKR e TPX
e5/4, COPX  Mr40.8,    boATH e5/21, CAI >39.35 e5/5, NVMI bo e5/14, BRKS bo e4/30, SI ebo e4/29,  5/5,
FOXF WAL
RS85 ebo e4/30, BLOK, HZO e4/23, SIVB 2yr bo e4/22,  PW bo e3/30,   bo e5/6, HIBB >Mr68.31 e3/20,  e7/17, TBBK
,  INMD SBNY

> 20.24 Mr30.49 e4/30, DKL RS78 e2/23, +XRT AVNW Mr99 e5/12, CROX e4/23,   e5/6, SQ e5/6, HUBS e5/6,   evol
> KLIC
> e7/21, TGH >26.5 Mr35.43 e5/4,   bo e4/30, JLL >178.55 RS78 e4/29, AMRK Mr65.03 e4/27, CADE Mr28.66 e4/29, ON bo
> AGCO
> e5/9, CMBM e5/12, COWN Mr86.12 e4/29, CUBI Mr36.93 e5/4, AM Mr10.27 e4/29, ASO e5/28, MBIN e4/23,   e4/29, DE
> DEN MTZ   HVT
> e5/21,   bo e5/18,   e4/30, TSE Mr75.84 e5/6, BIG e5/29, CASH e4/22, EVR bo e4/22,   e5/20, JOUT ATH e5/5,
> MVBF XPEL MX
> bo e4/28, RWJ na, VMI e4/22, WES Mr41.23 e5/5, EDUC e5/21, TVTY e5/6,   bo e5/14,  RVLV e5/13, + flag
> SNX ALLY DKS
> boe5/6, MYRG e4/29,   e6/25, URI e4/29, VAC e5/6, WSM e5/28,   e7/17,   bo e6/2, RCKY e4/28, LPX e5/5, AN
> RH SLM FCNCA TX
> e4/20,   bo e6/4,   >18.13 e7/22, IMKTA e5/7, ABCB e4/23, AMAT e5/20,   e4/28, ICHR e5/4,   e4/27, RBNC
> LGIH CTRN
> e4/27, BLDR e4/30,   e5/4, MHO e4/29, AMKR bo Mr65 e4/27, SKY e5/20, BZH e4/30, +  e5/28, SGH Mathr56.69
> SYX BECN YETI RM SAIA PAG
> e7/7,   e4/28,   Mr66.47 e5/7,   boATH e5/13, IAC e4/28,   e4/28,   e4/28, ACBI e4/22,   bo
> CHEF  NWS GMS
> e4/28,  Mr42.06 e4/28, LOB e4/21,   e5/7,   bo e6/25, GRBK lbbo Mr88 e5/11, LSCC bo e5/4, SBSW bo
> CBNK KNL OPY SEM SID TIPT
> e4/28, SF e4/30,   bo e4/30, FIX e4/27,   Mr27.26 e4/28,   e5/1,   e5/6,   e4/28,   >12.27 e5/7,
> ALGN  ERII bo  HWM e LOVE SSL STAA .
> ( e4/28,  e5/6,  5/6,   e6/9,   Mr 39.23 e4/28,   e5/6 ) .  Strong volume
> tends to lead price. Ut lorem ipsum, venenatis et aliquet in, suscipit sit amet tellus. Integer vestibulum luctus rhoncus. Proin at arcu mauris. Nam tempor ipsum quis commodo cursus. Aenean faucibus hendrerit aliquam. Curabitur ullamcorper, metus in volutpat pretium, diam purus laoreet diam, non pulvinar massa justo ac leo. Aenean vehicula, orci in rutrum sodales, neque nulla maximus purus, quis suscipit nulla nisi non nibh. Nunc a molestie nunc. Cras velit risus, eleifend ut aliquet rhoncus, ullamcorper non risus. Nam tristique facilisis purus, sed fringilla enim pulvinar vitae. Nunc dignissim consectetur molestie. Mauris id maximus lorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the substring between two strings:

```py
\(stocks-to-watch\s+are\s+in\s+the\s+following\s+paragraph\):([\s\S]*?)Strong\svolume
```

See [proof #1](https://regex101.com/r/ZFolIv/1).

After that you will be able to extract the matches you need from group #1 with your original `\b[A-Z]{2,4}\b`.

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  stocks-to-watch          'stocks-to-watch'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  are                      'are'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  in                       'in'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  the                      'the'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  following                'following'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  paragraph                'paragraph'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Strong                   'Strong'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  volume                   'volume'
```

Comment: Thanks for this but its the second bit I'm stuck with .." After that you will be able to extract the matches you need from group #1" is it possible to do this in one line search query, if not how would you approach this with python ?

Comment: @JimmyD This way: `[re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{2,4}\b', x) for x in re.findall(r'\(stocks-to-watch\s+are\s+in\s+the\s+following\s+paragraph\):([\s\S]*?)Strong\svolume', test_str)]`